# I can't change screen resolution on esprimo mobile V5535 with UBUNTU 16.04LTS

Tags: drivers, screen, display-resolution

I installed UBUNTU 16.04 on a old esprimo mobile V5535. My screen resolution is only 640 X 480. I would like to change on 1024 X 768 or 1280 X 800.How to do this ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Would you be able to provide more information in your question?  Are you having a hard time finding the option to change resolution, or have you found it, and unable to make any changes?

Comment: I've found it but i'm unable to make change (just the option : 600 X 480)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't, unless you write the driver yourself.

XORG and UBUNTU have decided not to support the sis671 graphics card that is in your laptop.

From what I have read you could rebuild the driver from code on github until 12.04/12.10. From 14.04 and onwards that is no longer possible.